# Probability: Estimating Database Size with N Smallest Random Values

Tags: probability, estimation, sample-size, database

*Note: This was first [posted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56830490/probability-estimating-nosql-query-size-count-using-random-samples), but I did not have much luck there.*

I have a very large database. Each item in the database is assigned a uniformly distributed random value $\geq 0$ and $<1$. This database is so large that performing a `COUNT` of a query (*i.e.*, determining how many results are in the query) is very slow. However, I'd like to use the random values to estimate the total size of a query (`COUNT`).

The idea is this:

1. Run a query and order the query by the random value. Random values are indexed, so it's fast.
2. Grab the lowest $N$ values, and see how big the largest value is, say $R$.
   Estimate COUNT as $N/R$

The question is two-part:

1. Is $N / R$ the best way to estimate `COUNT`? Maybe it should be $(N+1)/R$? Maybe we could look at the other values (average, variance, etc), and not just the largest value to get a better estimate?
2. What is the error margin on this estimated value of `COUNT`?

Comment: I'm curious: how can it happen that it's more efficient to report the smallest $N$ values rather than just the count of values?  Is it that the query is exploiting an index on these random values in a way that enables it to find those $N$ values first without finding the rest?

Comment: For those interested this has been posted on math stack exchange as well. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3280227/probability-estimating-database-size-with-n-smallest-random-values
Relevant because a similar question to @whuber came up there.

Comment: I hate to ask, but there is an answer to your question on StackOverflow. What is the problem with that answer?

Comment: @whuber in distributed systems that store massive amounts of data across many computers with many writes/deletes per second, it's still relatively easy to add/remove an ordered item, but it's difficult to maintain an accurate count of all items. This issue only arises when your database grows so large that it has to span many computers across a network. Insertion will only effect one node on the network, but maintaining a comprehensive count requires coordination across many nodes.

Comment: To clarify slightly, insertion will require coordination between O(log(COUNT)) number of nodes, while determining the COUNT will require coordination of O(COUNT) nodes, where "O" is algorithmic complexity. Databases that handle extremely large amounts of data (e.g., Google's BigTable) either don't support COUNT, or have large performance costs.